# Loopback v4 nested object(n.o.) without creating that n.o. as separate model

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I started with Loopback 4 a week back. And, I have been stuck in some issues for a long time.

I am trying to build a User model

```
@model()
export class Address {
  @property() addressLine1: string;
  @property() addressLine2: string;
  @property() pin: string;
}

@model()
export class User {
  @property() email: string;
  @property() password: string;
  @property() phone: string;
  @property() address: Address;
}
```

**Issue #1**

While I am trying to save the model from the API endpoint, I am getting the following error:

`Unhandled error in POST /users: 500 Error: can't resolve reference #/components/schemas/Address from id #`

I believe that loopback is trying to save the address as a model. I need that address to be saved as a json field in dynamoDB, instead of creating a new model.

Is there a key/property/setting to passed in the model through which I can ignore that from being created? I went through the tutorials and API docs but found nothing helpful.

**Issue #2**

`Address` model shows up in the `Swagger` only when `@model()` annotation is added to it

Is there a simpler way to put `Address` in the swagger without `@model`?

Note: I am using DynamoDB connector: [lb-dynamodb-connector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lb-connector-dynamodb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the below should work for you.

```
@model()
export class Address extends Model {
  @property() addressLine1: string;
  @property() addressLine2: string;
  @property() pin: string;
}

@model()
export class User extends Entity {
  @property() email: string;
  @property() password: string;
  @property() phone: string;
  @property({
    type: 'object',
  }) address: Address;
}
```

Although I have not worked with dynamo db connector. But that should work as per loopback model goes.

Comment: Tried it...not working. Maybe it is not implemented in the connector.

Comment: Well, It worked. I wonder why it didn't work when I tried a couple of days back.